# Need Regex For Enter mark content

Tags: regex, perl

The below content having enter mark i want capture that in regex please help.

I try `\s* and \t* and \r and \n` ..etc, but cant get.

```
dslkjflkds
lksdfds

slkdjlkds      


sdlkdslkjhgfsd          




slkdfjhldsjfds


slkjdsjhlsd

sldfldsjf

sldfjhldsjhflds
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I want to find the empty enter mark(that means empty para). I want to find and remove the empty para while streaming my content.

Comment: How is defined _empty para_?

Comment: I think he does not want empty lines.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to clear empty lines... If so,

I copied your text and tried to find more than one enter marks.

with this

```
(\n){2,}
```

works for me. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

There are *many* ways that you can do this in Perl. One fairly simply way, it from the command line, using the `-n`, `-i`, and `-e` flags described in [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html):

```
perl -ni -e 'print unless /^$/' <filename>
```

`-n` assumes this while loop around your statement:

```
while (<>) {
   # statements passed to -e go here
}
```

`-e` executes a statement

`-i` instructs that you want the operation to be performed in-place (modifying the original file). You can specify `-i.bak` if you wish to preserve the original file in a `.bak` file.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you expect?

```
$ perl -p00e';' file.txt 
dslkjflkds
lksdfds

slkdjlkds      

sdlkdslkjhgfsd          

slkdfjhldsjfds

slkjdsjhlsd

sldfldsjf

sldfjhldsjhflds
```